# Javascript - Overriding property (not methods) inside an Object

Tags: javascript

Let us explain the question with an example. I have a text box. The textbox (every textbox) has a property called 'value'. I want to over ride that `textbox.value` and comeup with and 
new thing. When the text in textbox is 'ranjan' then the `textbox.VALUE` property returns 'ranjan'. Now I want to thus overwrite this so that when you type `textbox.VALUE` you get a different thing say for example, RaNjAn or say, Mr. Ranjan or whatever.

We can over ride methods using Object.PROTOTYPE property. But how can we do it for non-function objects inside object for example the 'value' property in this case.

If i need to make the question more clear, please mention.

Regards - Ranjan.

Comment: Now everybody knows your name :)

Comment: You might find something useful in [MDN: Working with objects, getters/setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects). However, not all of that functionality works across all browsers.

Comment: :( that was general information.

Comment: What is your reason for needing this functionality? It is my experience that if you are trying something that is very difficult to do you are approaching things in the wrong way.

Answer (score 8):

You can define custom properties for your element using `Object.defineProperty`

If you have a case where you need to get the value of an element as `Mr. <value>` for example, then this approach will be useful. Overriding standard properties may not be such a good idea.

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/zvCGw/2/

**Code**:

```
var foo = document.getElementById('foo');

Object.defineProperty(foo, "xvalue", {
    get: function() {
        return 'Mr. ' + foo.value;
    },
    set: function(_newValue) {
        foo.value = _newValue;
    }
});

foo.xvalue = 'Hello';

alert(foo.xvalue);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is called type augmentation. In javscript there are types of things, such as the object type, array type, etc.

You can use the prototype to augment these built in types, for example, adding a new method that can be called on any object that is of the type array:

```
Array.prototype.myNewMethod = function() {
    //the method logic
}
```

Then you can call your method on any array:

```
[0,1,2].myNewMethod();
```

There is no INPUT type in JavaScript, DOM elements are classed as Objects. But you could jerry-rig something together that kind of does what you need, like this

```
Object.prototype.changeValue = function(el) {
    if (el.tagName === "INPUT") {
        return "Mr " + el.value;
    }
}


var testEl = document.getElementById("test");
document.write(testEl.changeValue(testEl))
```

Used in conjunction with this textbox:

```
<input id="test" value="Dan" />
```

You would then get the output 'Mr Dan'

However, this is not great, it's just to illustrate the point and is just something to get you started...

I made [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2VZyb/) so you can play around with it

Comment: This again is a workaround. You need to call textbox.changeValue() to change the value. I guess this is impossible to do this thing.

Comment: Yea, as I said, it's not great ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can redeclare value but it will do no good ;)

This example would do that if test is a textbox

```
var input = document.getElementById("test");

Object.defineProperty(input, "value", {
    get : function () {
        return "'" + this["value"] + "'";
    },
    set : function (val) {
        this["value"] = val;
    }
});

input.value = "Hello World";
alert(input.value);
```

Unfortunately, "this.value" will reference the getter causing infinite recursion.

Once redefined, the original value will no longer exist so you will have crippled the element object.

At least as far as I have been able to test.

Answer (score 1):

If the property you're trying to override can also be represented by an HTML attribute (e.g. an input's `value`), then you can use `getAttribute` and `setAttribute`.

```
Object.defineProperty(myInputElement, 'value', {
    get: function () {
        return myInputElement.getAttribute('value');
    },
    set: function (value) {
        myInputElement.setAttribute('value', value);
    }
});
```

Note, however, that this override itself cannot be overridden without re-implementing it.